# How to hook into XirSys' signaling server instead of Priologic

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn, easyrtc, xirsys

I'm using EasyRTC to develop a video chat app. The ICE configuration is set up following the guide on XirSys site:

```
easyrtc.on("getIceConfig", function(connectionObj, callback){
  var iceConfig = [];

  request.post('https://api.xirsys.com/getIceServers', {
    form: {
        ident: '***',
        secret: '***',
        domain: '***',
        application: 'default',
        room: 'default',
        secure: 1
    },
  },
  function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(arguments);
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        iceConfig = JSON.parse(body).d.iceServers;
        console.log(iceConfig);
        callback(null, iceConfig);
    }
    else {
        console.log(error);
    }
  });
});
```

It's working, I can run the EasyRTC demos but there's no STUN/TURN hit in the XirSys console. I suspect this is because the app is still using the public signaling server from Priologic.

The documentation on XirSys' site mentions a "later tutorial" for how to change the signaling server but I couldn't find any.

Does anybody know how to do it?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
The problem seems to persist after migrating to the new platform version and changing the request above with:

```
request({
            url: 'https://service.xirsys.com/ice',
            qs: {
                ident: '***',
                secret: '***',
                domain: '***',
                application: "default",
                room: "default",
                secure: 1
            },
            json: true
        },
        function(error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                iceConfig = body.d.iceServers;
                callback(null, iceConfig);
            } else {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I answered this question directly via email, but for consistency, will update here as well.

The new XirSys platform went live, yesterday, which has full usage monitoring capabilities within the dashboard.  Please give this a go, but remember that the meters will not update until 10 minutes after a disconnection from the TURN server.  Also, it may help to use Wireshark or some other network sniffer, so as to accurately see how your connections are failing / working.

Many thanks,
Lee
CTO @ XirSys

Comment: Hi Lee, thank you very much for the answer! I migrated to the new API version but the problem seems to persist, counters are still zero; additionally, the dashboard doesn't show any of my domains/apps/rooms, although I did create them (and I am able to see them when following the "Show domains" link).

Comment: This has since been resolved using the XirSys ticketing system.